# What would be an example of a nontrivial, i.e. multi-sheeted, covering of the torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

What would be an example of a nontrivial, i.e. multi-sheeted, covering of the torus?  I would greatly appreciate any help that you could give me.

Comment: Can you find a non-trivial covering of the circle $S^1$?

Comment: well yes, but how does that help?

Comment: The torus is $S^1 \times S^1$.

Comment: Quick note: the cover will be a torus (besides the universal cover), since for an n-fold cover $A\to B$ we have $\chi(A)=n\chi(B)$, and here we have $\chi(B)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The torus is $\cong \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$. Let $\Lambda$ be any proper sublattice of $\mathbb Z^2$ (for example the one spanned by $(3,4)$ and $(8,-6)$), then $\mathbb R^2/\Lambda$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, strictly he is looking for a map, not another construction for the torus :-)